# How do you implement OmniAuth on Rails 2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am trying to implement Facebook and Twitter authentication using Omniauth for an existing Rails 2.2 application. So far I have been unable to find any advise on how to do this in Rails 2.2 - hence this question. I have two questions to ask -

1. I understand Rack support for Rails was introduced from 2.3 and I believe Rack is needed for OmniAuth. So is it even possible to use OmniAuth on a Rails 2.2 website and why ?
2. If it is possible to implement OmniAuth - how would you do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the default config.gem "omniauth" ... to get it working i did the following:

1.Install omniauth **manually**

```
sudo gem install omniauth
```

2.Require it **before** the Rails Initializer in the config/environment.rb file.

```
require 'omniauth'
Rails::Initializer.run do |config| ....
```

3.In development.rb file i've added the following configuration

```
config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
 provider :facebook, "XXx", "YYYY", :scope => % (email user_birthday publish_stream offline_access)
end
```

Add as many providers as you want here .... everything else should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer moski - I am going to try this out now. I took the liberty of making a couple of minor edits on your answer as well.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and I am getting the following error - config/environments/development.rb:19:in `load_environment': undefined method `middleware' for #<Rails::Configuration:0xb6e48c50> (NoMethodError)
The Rails version I am using is 2.2.2, Omniauth 0.1.6

Comment: @Nikhil, any luck at getting this fixed?  Am stumbling around on the same problem...

Comment: @slotishtype sorry I couldn't get around this problem so I had to shelve it. May try it again after I get around to upgrading to Rails 3